# updating springboot version from 2.6.7 to 2.7.3 gives issue org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmeter-5.0

we are having SQL function which runs for particular junit 5 test cases on in-memory database hsqldb. it was working fine before upgrading spring boot to 2.7.3 .

Function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION db_schema.getEmplyoeeReport(deliveryStatus text, limitRecord integer) RETURNS setof db_schema.employee_usage_report_delivery_status AS ' BEGIN RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM db_schema.employee_usage_report_delivery_status usageDelivery WHERE usageDelivery.status = deliveryStatus LIMIT limitRecord; END;
 ' LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

```
 org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [java.lang.String trustStorePassword] in constructor [public com.abc.demo.admin.rest.demoServerABCUserTest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate,com.abc.demo.admin.rest.manager.service.ApplicationPropertyService,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:239)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:183)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:74)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:302)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:280)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: after updating application .properties  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;sql.syntax_pgs=true

  getting  type not found or user lacks privilege